# Cannot install scipy on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, numpy, installation, scipy

I have repeatedly tried to install SciPy on my mac, using various different tutorials, but whenever I run the nosetests or try to use SciPy I always get "ImportError: No module named scipy." Even http://www.scipy.org/install.html didn't work, even though I have MacPorts already. Is there any foolproof tutorial on how to install scipy? I can't get it to work at all.

Comment: I think this could work on Catalina and below (haven't tested): https://github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack/blob/master/install_superpack.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: I couldn't get it to work at all so I just downloaded Enthought Canopy. Not ideal that MacPorts tutorials failed so completely but it doesn't matter now.